# Could somebody help me with CRC division?

Tags: crc

I am doing practice problems for midterms. The question is as follows:

> Suppose we want to transmit a message 11001001 and protect it from error using the CRC polynomial x^3+1. Use polynomial long division to determine the message that should be transmitted (show all steps to get CRC bits and the complete message transmitted).

In this only [solution](https://nanopdf.com/download/homework-4-17_pdf) I could find, the long division stops before the final zero. For the work I have done, there's an extra 1 in the quotient (pic attached). Why is the work in the online solution so different to mine?

[image: long division work]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is correct, the solution in the link is missing the 1 bit. In hex the example is dividing 648 / 9, quotient = d3, remainder = 3, which is what you have in your question. (It was recommended to post this as an answer so others browsing question would know it has an answer).